# Have Firefox open video links in IE Metro possible?

Tags: windows-8, firefox, internet-explorer, hyperlink, cross-browser

Is it possible that I click a video link (youtube etc) in firefox and instead pf opening in another tab right there in ff, it opens up in IE metro mode? By either a script or a plugin or whatever?

Comment: No;  Its not possible.  The main reason is that Firefox does not have a Modern UI version released and won't have one.  They have discontinued all plans to release one.

Comment: @laggingreflex Would [Open in IE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-in-ie/) be helpful??